# Problems with wrapping a C++ code

Tags: c++, c

To try the C++ code wrapping within C, I used the following:
header.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void func();
```

source.cpp

```
#include "header.h" 
#include <iostream>
extern "C" void func()
{
std::cout << "This is C++ code!" << std::endl;
}
```

and source.c

```
#include "header.h"
int main()
{
func();
}
```

To compile and link, I used the following sequence:

```
g++ -c source.cpp
gcc source.c source.o -o myprog
```

The error I get is:
ence to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
source.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to`std::basic_ostream >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream >& (*)(std::basic_ostream >&))'
source.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
source.cpp:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to`std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
source.cpp:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
source.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to`__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

How can I make this simple code compile and run? It should serve as a basis for my future
development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Link with g++ as well:

```
g++ -c source.cpp
g++ source.c source.o -o myprog
```

Or better:

```
g++ -c source.cpp -o source_cpp.o
gcc -c source.c -o source_c.o
g++ -o myprog source_cpp.o source_c.o
```

Best to avoid the common prefix source.{cpp,c} as it causes confusion.

Comment: Thanks, the first option works :). How could one execute the above option 1 in just one line?

Comment: `g++ -o myprog source.cpp source.c`

Comment: Doesn't this compile the c source as c++?

Comment: I don't *think* so as the .c will tell the compiler to do the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

You'll still have to link with the C++ linker:

```
gcc -o source-c.o source.c
g++ -o source-p.o source.cpp
g++ -o myprog source-c.o source-p.o
```

Your C++ object file will need to resolve symbols from the C++ library, which only the C++ linker will pull in automatically. (Alternatively, you could specify the library manually for the C linker.)

Answer (score 0):

you can't do that, you can compile C code with gcc, and then link it with c++ objects with g++, referring to the symbols defined in the C objects via the extern keyword, but you can't do the opposite

Comment: It not only possible, it's very frequently used. That is why functions in header system header files are declared as `extern "C"`. The only things you can't export this way are classes and objects.